# Gatling 2: Arithmetic average metric in report

Tags: report, average, metrics, gatling

Currently the Gatling report provides the following metrics

- minimum
- maximum
- 50th percentile
- 75th percentile
- 95th percentile
- 99th percentile
- mean
- standard deviation

but it does not provide the arithmetic average.

I have found a [related discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/yaKE5I2e5TA) about this in the google group, but am not sure about the outcome.

In general I agree that the average is not a good metric to be used. Percentiles are way more representative - no doubt about that. So from an engineering point of view I don't see a problem with the currently supported metrics.

But a problem arises from a legal point of view (as usual :). It seems there are ill conceived SLAs out there which explicitly define average request duration. Since Gatling does not emit the average metric, boneheaded customers won't accept the "Ready-to-present HTML reports" as a proof that such SLA terms are met...

So my question is: Is there a way to add the average metric to the report output?

Comment: As far as I know, mean (reported) is the same as arithmetic average.  Do you have data that shows otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mean and average are [exactly the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean).

Comment: And then, yes, expressing SLAs in terms of means is a great way to bury your head in the sand...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I got my wires crossed and mistook mean for median. Duh!

Comment: Ok Mean= average, so this seems like a bug, i have a mean of 5ms, while the min is 8

[![How about this?][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b6pqx.png